# lat/lon to utm to lat/lon is extremely flawed, how come?

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, utm

I've tried the following, 
input: lat/lon data
then I'll calculate a box around it by, let's say 50 m, so +/- 50 m on easting/northing value.

Now I reconvert it to lat/lon and with a script:

http://robotics.ai.uiuc.edu/~hyoon24/LatLongUTMconversion.py I get a result that just can't be, lon before is around 7, afterwards around 2.

```
zone, easting, northing = LLtoUTM(23, location.get_lat(), location.get_lon()) 

topUTM = northing + error
bottomUTM = northing - error
leftUTM = easting - error
rightUTM = easting + error
left, top = UTMtoLL(23, leftUTM, topUTM, zone)
```

Is the error in my code, or might be the script flawed?

So I've tried to use pyproj, just lat/lon to utm to lat/lon to see what happens

```
>>> p = pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=32, ellps='WGS84')
>>> p
<pyproj.Proj object at 0x7ff9b8487dd0>
>>> x,y = p(47.9941214, 7.8509671)
>>> print x,y
5159550.36822 1114087.43925
>>> print p(x,y,inverse=True)
(47.971558538495991, 7.8546573140162605)
```

And here it's not as extremely far off as with the script from above, but it still seems strongly enough incorrect as to not be able to use it. How come? What can I do to get more exact results?

EDIT:

I ran test() and it all tests passed.

in epsg file there is no such thing. The closest I've found was this:

```
<32632> +proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs <>
```

no tmerc. Also What would I need to pass the towgs84 as parameters? The ones above?

Answer (score 62):

I've created a small UTM conversion library for Python last week and uploaded it to the Python Package Index: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/utm

I have compared it to using pyproj and it is faster and more accurate. Given your sample data, this is the result:

```
>>> import utm

>>> u = utm.from_latlon(47.9941214, 7.8509671)
>>> print u
(414278, 5316285, 32, 'T')

>>> print utm.to_latlon(*u)
(47.994157948891505, 7.850963967574302)
```

**UPDATE:** Richards [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18620929/1478093) below describes the real solution for this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out, @TBieniek!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this implementation, absolutely valuable!

Comment: Is utm.to_latlon broadcastable on a numpy array?

Comment: Thanks for creating a whole freakin Python package and uploading it on pip to answer a StackOverflow question.  Truly above and beyond

Comment: Thanks! So much easier to use (and install) than pyproj!

Comment: Hi, I've tried your pypi package, it does seem much easier to use.
I have a conversion error however, utm.to_latlon(246000, 9855098, 37, 'S') returns (88.35340991983618, -159.09274162642123), am I doing something wrong in the input?

Comment: Careful that the conversion has flaws. I've run over a dataset in zone 31 V and there's 100m+ error...

Answer (score 34):

The error is in your code.

First off, the PyProj issue listed in one of the other answers is real. You should check your epsg file and make sure it includes the line

```
<2392> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=24 +k=1.000000 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-90.7,-106.1,-119.2,4.09,0.218,-1.05,1.37 +units=m +no_defs no_defs <>
```

Note the `towgs84` parameter.

Your problem with PyProj stems from mis-using the projection command.

If we take 47.9941214N, 7.8509671E and [convert to UTM](http://www.rcn.montana.edu/resources/tools/coordinates.aspx) we get Zone 32, 414278 Easting, 5316286 Northing.

You perform the following PyProj operations:

```
p = pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=32, ellps='WGS84')
>>> x,y = p(47.9941214, 7.8509671)
>>> print x,y
5159550.36822 1114087.43925
>>> print p(x,y,inverse=True)
(47.971558538495991, 7.8546573140162605)
```

But, if we consult the PyProj [documentation](http://pyproj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/pyproj.Proj-class.html#section-MethodDetails), we see the following:

> Calling a Proj class instance with the arguments lon, lat will convert
>   lon/lat (in degrees) to x/y native map projection coordinates (in
>   meters).

Let's try running the OP's PyProj operations again, but switch the order of the lon/lat arguments:

```
p = pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=32, ellps='WGS84')
>>> x,y = p(7.8509671, 47.9941214)
>>> print x,y
414278.16731 5316285.59492
>>> print p(x,y,inverse=True)
(7.850967099999812, 47.994121399999784)
```

The operation inverts itself (pretty much) perfectly!

To answer the first part of your question, if you look in `http://robotics.ai.uiuc.edu/~hyoon24/LatLongUTMconversion.py` at the definition of `UTMtoLL`, you find the following:

```
UTMtoLL(ReferenceEllipsoid, northing, easting, zone)
```

Yet you use `UTMtoLL(23, leftUTM, topUTM, zone)` where leftUTM is an Easting and topUTM is a Northing.

Therefore, in the case of both your first script and PyProj, you've used the wrong order of arguments.

It's a good reminder to always double- (or triple-) check your work before suggesting that someone else's is wrong. That said, Python's documentation is [not the greatest](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2013/02/19/the-python-documentation-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/) and PyProj's documentation in this instance is cryptic at best. A nice web-based explanation of this command and accompanied by examples of its usage would have probably prevented angst on your part.

Comment: Is there any way to automatically detect UTM zone from latitude longitude.

Comment: Is there better doc on this since 2013 ?
(GDAL seems to fall over on roundtrip lat-lon -> utm -> lat-lon, see this
[plot](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/396) )

Comment: @Lostman:  `math.floor(((lon + 180) % 360) / 6) + 1` should work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186496/determining-utm-zone-to-convert-from-longitude-latitude

Answer (score 4):

I have no problem with pyproj, try the following code

```
from pyproj import Proj

Lat = 52.063098675
Lon = -114.132980348 #Calgary

ZoneNo = "11" #Manually input, or calcuated from Lat Lon
myProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone="+ZoneNo+",\
+north +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") #north for north hemisphere
UTMx, UTMy = myProj(Lon, Lat)

########################################

#UTM ==> Lat Lon:
ZoneNo = "11" #Manually input or from other sources
myProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone="+\
ZoneNo+", +north +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
Lon2, Lat2 = myProj(UTMx, UTMy,inverse=True)

print Lat2
print Lon2
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue with pyProj sounds just like the one described here:

http://code.google.com/p/pyproj/issues/detail?id=3

which is resolved:

`solved! in epsg file there must be`

`<2392> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=24 +k=1.000000 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl
+towgs84=-90.7,-106.1,-119.2,4.09,0.218,-1.05,1.37 +units=m +no_defs  no_defs <>`

`note the towgs84 parameter!`

Check that thread out if you want to continue to use pyproj.

Also, does the `test()` function of the module work? Have you tried any of the scripts that come with it in the `test` directory?

Comment: Those hoping that Ubuntu 13.04 Raring would include an up-to-date PyProj would find themselves mistaken. Install from source!