# Checking whether coordinates fall within a given radius

Tags: r, geospatial

I have a list of co-ordinates of certain bus stops in this format

```
 Bus_Stop_ID     lat          long
 A               -34.04199    18.61747
 B               -33.92312    18.44649
```

I then have a list of certain shops

```
 Shop_ID     lat          long
 1            -34.039350  18.617964  
 2            -33.927820  18.410520
```

I would like to check whether the shops fall within a 500 metre radius from the bus stop. Ultimately, the final dataset would look something like this where the Bus_Stop column indicates T/F and Bus_Stop_ID shows the relevant BUS ID(s) for that shop if Bus_Stop == T -

```
 Shop_ID     lat          long       Bus_Stop Bus_ID  
 1            -34.039350  18.617964  TRUE     A
 2            -33.927820  18.410520  FALSE    #NA
```

Does anyone have an idea about how I can go about this using R? I've seen the package `geosphere` but have struggled to understand it given my relative inexperience in the spatial domain. Any ideas or packages you could recommend? Thank you

Comment: You may want to see my update as it is a more scalable approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Updated to more scalable solution:

The previous answer (still included below) is not suited for large data sets. The reason is that we need to compute the distance for each pair of `shops` and `bus`. Therefore both the memory and computation scale as `O(N*M)` for `N` shops and `M` buses. A more scalable solution uses a data structure such as a KD-Tree to perform nearest neighbor search for each shop. The advantage here is that the computational complexity becomes `O(M*logM)` for building the KD-Tree for the bus stops and `O(N*logM)` for searching the nearest neighbor for each shop.

To do this, we can use `nn2` from the `RANN` package. The complication here is that `nn2` deals only with Euclidean distances and does not know anything about lat/long. Therefore, we need to convert the lat/long coordinates to some map projection (i.e. UTM) in order to use it correctly (i.e., in order to compute the Euclidean distance between shops and bus stops correctly).

**Note:** The following borrows heavily from Josh O'Brien's solutions for [determining the UTM zone from a longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186496/determining-utm-zone-to-convert-from-longitude-latitude) and for [converting lat/long to UTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639967/converting-latitude-and-longitude-points-to-utm), so he should take a bow.

```
## First define a function from Josh OBrien's answer to convert
## a longitude to its UTM zone
long2UTM <- function(long) {
  (floor((long + 180)/6) %% 60) + 1
}

## Assuming that all points are within a zone (within 6 degrees in longitude),
## we use the first shop's longitude to get the zone.
z <- long2UTM(shops[1,"long"])

library(sp)
library(rgdal)

## convert the bus lat/long coordinates to UTM for the computed zone
## using the other Josh O'Brien linked answer
bus2 <- bus
coordinates(bus2) <- c("long", "lat")
proj4string(bus2) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

bus.xy <- spTransform(bus2, CRS(paste0("+proj=utm +zone=",z," ellps=WGS84")))

## convert the shops lat/long coordinates to UTM for the computed zone
shops2 <- shops
coordinates(shops2) <- c("long", "lat")
proj4string(shops2) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

shops.xy <- spTransform(shops2, CRS(paste0("+proj=utm +zone=",z," ellps=WGS84")))

library(RANN)

## find the nearest neighbor in bus.xy@coords for each shops.xy@coords
res <- nn2(bus.xy@coords, shops.xy@coords, 1)
## res$nn.dist is a vector of the distance to the nearest bus.xy@coords for each shops.xy@coords
## res$nn.idx is a vector of indices to bus.xy of the nearest bus.xy@coords for each shops.xy@coords
shops$Bus_Stop <- res$nn.dists <= 500
shops$Bus_ID <- ifelse(res$nn.dists <= 500, bus[res$nn.idx,"Bus_Stop_ID"], NA)
```

Although more complicated, this approach is much better suited for realistic problems where you may have large numbers of shops and bus stops. Using the same supplied data:

```
print(shops)
##  Shop_ID       lat     long Bus_Stop Bus_ID
##1       1 -34.03935 18.61796     TRUE      A
##2       2 -33.92782 18.41052    FALSE   <NA>
```

---

You can do this using the package `geosphere`. Here, I'm assuming that your first data frame is named `bus`, and your second data frame is named `shops`:

```
library(geosphere)
g <- expand.grid(1:nrow(shops), 1:nrow(bus))
d <- matrix(distGeo(shops[g[,1],c("long","lat")], bus[g[,2],c("long","lat")]),
            nrow=nrow(shops))
shops$Bus_Stop <- apply(d, 1, function(x) any(x <= 500))
shops$Bus_ID <- bus[apply(d, 1, function(x) {
                                  c <-which(x <= 500)
                                  if(length(c)==0) NA else c[1]
                                }), "Bus_Stop_ID"]
print(shops)
##  Shop_ID       lat     long Bus_Stop Bus_ID
##1       1 -34.03935 18.61796     TRUE      A
##2       2 -33.92782 18.41052    FALSE   <NA>
```

Notes:

1. We first use `expand.grid` to enumerate all pair combinations of `shops` and `bus` stops. These are ordered by `shops` first.
2. We then compute the distance matrix `d` using `geosphere::distGeo`. Note here that the input expects (lon, lat) coordinates. `distGeo` returns distances in meters. The resulting `d` matrix is `now(shops)` by `now(bus)` so that each row gives the distance from a shop to each bus stop.
3. We then see if there is a bus stop within 500 meters of each shop by applying the function `any(x <= 500)` for each row `x` in `d` using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`.
4. Similarly, we can extract the column of `d` (corresponding to the row in `bus`) for the first shop that is within 500 meters using `which` instead of `any` in our applied function. Then use this result to select the `Bus_Stop_ID` from `bus`.

By the way, we don't have to `apply` the condition `x <= 500` twice. The following will also work:

```
shops$Bus_ID <- bus[apply(d, 1, function(x) {
                                  c <-which(x <= 500)
                                  if(length(c)==0) NA else c[1]
                                }), "Bus_Stop_ID"]
shops$Bus_Stop <- !is.na(shops$Bus_ID)
```

and is more efficient.

Data:

```
bus <- structure(list(Bus_Stop_ID = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A", "B"
), class = "factor"), lat = c(-34.04199, -33.92312), long = c(18.61747, 
18.44649)), .Names = c("Bus_Stop_ID", "lat", "long"), class = "data.frame",  row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

shops <- structure(list(Shop_ID = 1:2, lat = c(-34.03935, -33.92782), 
long = c(18.617964, 18.41052), Bus_ID = structure(c(1L, NA
), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Bus_Stop = c(TRUE, 
FALSE)), .Names = c("Shop_ID", "lat", "long", "Bus_ID", "Bus_Stop"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What an elegant solution which works superbly. Thank you very much @aichao

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: added `dput` for `bus` and `shops`.

Answer (score 1):

My first approach would be to just use [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) and check whether the resulting value is greater or equal 0.

You could then use an IF clause and check T/F conditions.

I hope this helps.

PS: In my imagination, a distance of 500m would be a rather flat representation of the Earth's surface, so I don't think it's needed to use some geoid packages.

Comment: You're right about the earth being essentially flat over such small areas. Even in this situation, though, a nice thing about **geosphere** is that it will take lat/long inputs and return distances in meters.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien is correct. In addition, a degree in longitude is not the same distance as degree of latitude except at the equator because the Earth is an ellipsoid instead of a rectangular box. Therefore, your distance in meters need to account for that.