# Python matplotlib basemap using northing and easting coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to plot UTM coordinates (easting and northing) on a map and I wanted to do that with the matplotlib basemap toolkit in python.

Is there a way to use these coordinates directly or do I have to convert them into lat and long coordinates? If I have to convert them is there an easy way to do it?

thank you!

Comment: I don't think that Basemap accepts UTM coordinates, for the conversion from UTM to lat/lon you might want to look into e.g. [GDAL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found an answer:
At http://pypi.python.org/pypi/utm there is a UTM conversion library (written by TBieniek). It is also possible to convert UTM with pyproj.

I found the answer here:
[lat/lon to utm to lat/lon is extremely flawed, how come?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778288/lat-lon-to-utm-to-lat-lon-is-extremely-flawed-how-come)