# How to Convert this coordinates to Latitudinal's and longitudinal's in Python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, geodjango, coordinate-transformation

```
 {
 "type": "MultiPolygon",
 "coordinates": [[[
    [6707794.77817316, 1952512.97762237],
    [6707794.43138905, 1952566.21209599],
    [6707897.49942442, 1952567.26754007],
    [6707897.9039513, 1952513.5347079],
    [6707794.77817316, 1952512.97762237]
  ]]]
}
```

I am very new to GeoDjango. These are my Geojson coordinates.

These are the Coordinates for Parcel data that belongs to Sacramento City. 
How to convert these coordinates into Lat Long in Python

Comment: Can Anyone tell me that What format is this coordinates. I mean is this in UTM? EPSG projection?

Comment: Can anyone suggest the correct library to convert these coordinates to LatLong

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) could be a good start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert the UTM to Lat/Long in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773815/how-to-convert-the-utm-to-lat-long-in-python)